How to read when the professor changes mind and rejects you
In my PhD program, I would like to go abroad to visit a foreign university, and ideally engage in research there.
The thing is, I have met a relatively famous professor, who has  agreed, in-person, with the idea of me coming to his university. I was just obliged to write him an email and we would solve all the other things afterwards.
So, the thing is, when I came back from the conference, I had to solve a few very urgent problems first, and only after that, I wrote the email (it was around 25 days after we have spoken). In this email, I have provided a detailed description of my research interests (1.5 pages), and plans (when I intend to finish my current projects). Also, I have tried to incorporate a short note on how I could connect my research interests with his (I know that this should be a priority, but isn't this something that gets revealed during the stay). Additionally, I have mentioned that I would like to stay there for more than 2 months (which was not communicated before).
Then, he just emailed me a substantially weird response, stating that he is not the right person to supervise me, because he lives in a different country; thus, we would meet only once per a week. This reason is strange to me, because this was already established when we have met during the conference.
This leaves me confused and I do not know how to interpret it. So, I came with a few hypotheses:

He was dissatisfied with my research interests
He did not find much connection between my and his interests
He was dissatisfied with the length of my stay
He initially did not think I would need a supervision, but just a pure visit instead
He was dissatisfied with how long it took me to send him an email

Which of these hypotheses may be true? Is it possible to rank these hypotheses according to the probability of them being correct? Why do professors usually change their minds?

We cannot tell nor can we read the professor's mind. Thus, is question is unanswerable. Sorry.

Is it unanswerable even "on average"? Why do professors usually change their minds?

@Athaeneus Because most professors are in fact human beings. Possibly what he meant to offer and what you proposed did not actually match. Maybe there is a difference between what seems like a plausible idea (ah, it would be great if you can visit!) and what is actually practically possible (ah, this would be...a lot of paperwork). Maybe he had a completely different idea of what you were proposing, and meant to invite you to apply for, say, a post doc when you finished your studies or to come for a day and give a talk, whereas you had in mind a visit to research while still a PhD student.

@BryanKrause But human beings have certain motivations, certain agenda... If I was in this situation with you (you = the professor), what would be the most probable cause of you acting as such?

@Athaeneus I think it's better to focus your time elsewhere.

As other commenters said, this is unanswerable but I still want to give another hypothesis:
6. The professor simply forgot about you.
Maybe this sounds ridiculous but when I was writing my bachelor's thesis, the supervising professor (who was also advisor) could not remember who I was after meeting me twice already. Professors are busy people and communicate with a lot of students an colleagues, so there is a chance that you just slipped his mind, especially after your extended wait for contacting him.

Are you sure he wanted you to come visit as a visiting scholar vs that he wanted you to come for the day and give a talk?

Are you sure that the professor knows that the author of this email and the person they met at the conference are the same person, and that they remember your conversation during the conference? That is, did you remind them in your email about the content of your conversation at the conference?

None of those options matter. You tried something, and for whatever confluence of reasons, it did not work out. It is truly not worth any mental energy on your end at this point.
What I can suggest in the future is follow up sooner, and your follow up should be a friendly email, rather than a multi-page un-prompted job application. The latter can follow if your potential host expresses/confirms their willingness to host.


who has agreed, in-person, with the idea of me coming to his
university. I was just obliged to write him an email [..]
Additionally, I have mentioned that I would like to stay there for
more than 2 months (which was not communicated before).

Maybe he meant you visiting for a talk, i.e. for 1 hour or so, not for two months. My guess is that you confused a polite invitation to stay in touch ("write me an email and let's discuss the details of your visit") with an invitation as a visiting scholar.
My 2 cents are that usually, at the PhD level, there must be some communication between supervisors and possible host. So I am almost sure that you writing diretctly to the professor a detailed research plan "out of the blue" was overwhelming to the professor.
When you are invited to be a visitor in some group, you should be asking yourself "who is paying my visit?". If you have a clear answer, then there is a concrete lead, otherwise it is just talking to be confirmed.
Be glad they showed interest, get over this possibiity, offer to visiit their group to give a talk, keep up the good job.
tl;dr: there is no clear rejection, nor acceptance of the original definition of visit you discussed, so there is no "change of mind" to be understood.
